# Dropzone CSRF token mismatch Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, csrf, laravel-5.5, dropzone.js

I am using Dropzone to upload images using Laravel 5.  After Dropzone makes the put call to my URL I get the following error:

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:

However, when I look at the payload for the request the token is present:

> ------WebKitFormBoundary91A7BYrMsDcGTEvx Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_method"
>
> PUT
>   ------WebKitFormBoundary91A7BYrMsDcGTEvx Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_token"
>
> j3NbjibYF7k8g2w1P0enw6YVfDrDvCGKFMCFt4NX
>   ------WebKitFormBoundary91A7BYrMsDcGTEvx Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"

Here is my JS:

```
    Dropzone.options.realDropzone = {
        url: '/user/manage/10',
        method: 'PUT',
        paramName: 'file',
        uploadMultiple: false,
        parallelUploads: 100,
        previewsContainer: '#dropzonePreview',
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        maxFiles: 10,
        autoProcessQueue: false,

        init: function () {
            var dropZone = this;

            this.element.querySelector("#save").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();

                console.log("clicked submit");
                dropZone.processQueue();
            });
        },
    };
```

My form:

```
{!! Form::model($asset, ['method' => 'PUT', 'class' => 'dropzone', 'id' => 'real-dropzone', 'action' => ['UserManagementController@update', $asset->id], 'file' => true]) !!}
```

My controller:

```
   public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        return dd(FileRequest::file('file'));
    }
```

Comment: So I just found out that when I submit the request with Dropzone there is no data being sent to my controller which is why I get the token mismatch.  Any ideas why dropzone is not submitting the whole form?

Answer (score 20):

Try to add the token in your Dropzone options:

```
sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {
    formData.append("_token", "{{ csrf_token() }}");
},
```

Comment: Bravo !
I was integrating Dropzone into my normal form. I was gettting the same issue for last 2 days and now on 3rd day, I read your answer and It simply solved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can just add `{{ csrf_field() }}` in your form

Comment: sorry, but how about if inside vue component?

Comment: You can have more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45523101/how-to-refer-laravel-csrf-field-inside-a-vue-template

Answer (score 5):

My working code for Laravel 5.6:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="dropzone dropzone-previews" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    $("div#my-awesome-dropzone").dropzone({
        url: "{{ url('/upload') }}",
        headers: {
            'x-csrf-token': CSRF_TOKEN,
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**HTML code in a blade file**

```html
<head>
    …
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone"></div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
new Dropzone('#my-dropzone', {
    url: '/upload',
    headers: {
        'x-csrf-token': document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content,
    },
});
```