# How to refer laravel csrf field inside a vue template

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have a vue template that contains a form:

```
<form id="logout-form" :action="href" method="POST" style="display: none;">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

In laravel, forms must have a csrf_field() defined. But within a vue component, the statement `{{ csrf_field() }}` means that I have a method named `csrf_field` in my vue instance and I am calling it.

How do I add csrf_field under this circumstance?

Comment: You can send CSRF token as header `headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN']`.And also store it into into the meta tag of your app, and later on just get it for instance with `document.querySelector`.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you have the token in the meta tag of your header (view)

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

you could access the token using

```
data() {
    return {
        csrf: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
    }
}
```

And add a hidden input field within the form and bind the csrf property to the value like this:

```
<form id="logout-form" :action="href" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">
</form>
```

Comment: I used `document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content` to get csrf data and work now! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using axios with Vue2 for your ajax requests you can just add the following (usually in your bootstrap.js file):

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};
```

Comment: Axios already provides this by default. If you're using axios and add this snippet you'll actually be breaking your calls by duplicating the encrypted csrf token cookie.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this package: `npm install vue-laravel-csrf`

Usage: `<form v-csrf-token>`

Answer (score 0):

This is how i use it:

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

Put that in your form.

and in your vue script you can simply

```
methods: {
                submitForm: function(e) {

                  var form = e.target || e.srcElement;
                  var action = form.action;
```

get the form and his action then the data value will be:

```
data: $(form).serialize()
```

This works perfectly for me and gives no errors at all.