# What cause 'Can't verify CSRF token authenticity' and '422' errors on upload image with dropzone JS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf, dropzone.js, ruby-on-rails-6, dropzone

Working on app for months that has few models accept image upload with dropzone JS using ActiveStorage, and out of no where I can't upload images anymore using dropzone anymore. The only thing I know I changed across the app is changed view engine from ERB to HAML. Could that cause the issue.?

I spent hours searching for a solution, but nothing works. Here is the app error when I attempt to upload an image.

```
Error creating Blob for "image_name.jpg". Status: 422
```

And here is terminal log:

```
Started GET "/rails/active_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--45a242e52828942cb9933781663d53482286244d/20200506181119-92c98aced52da742c66eef7d5ce34ff7.jpg" for ::1 at 2021-03-26 23:52:42 +0400


Processing by ActiveStorage::DiskController#show as JPEG
Parameters: {"encoded_key"=>"[FILTERED]", "filename"=>"20200506181119-92c98aced52da742c66eef7d5ce34ff7"}
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 471)

Started POST "/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads" for ::1 at 2021-03-27 05:21:48 +0400
Processing by ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"blob"=>{"filename"=>"88a04c2e5f589fcebda2641d00b8427f.jpg", "content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "byte_size"=>511762, "checksum"=>"y/nNLQR9mGaB5haUie2M5Q=="}, "direct_upload"=>{"blob"=>{"filename"=>"88a04c2e5f589fcebda2641d00b8427f.jpg", "content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "byte_size"=>511762, "checksum"=>"y/nNLQR9mGaB5haUie2M5Q=="}}}


Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1029)


ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken - ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken:
```

I'm using Rails6, and ruby 3. No calling API involve at this stage. I noticed that uploading images with dropzone JS cause this issue. And upload without dropzone JS works fine. What could be the cause?

Here is console error:

```
dropzone.js:8185 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
        at Dropzone.emit (dropzone.js:8185)
        at dropzone.js:10197
        at dropzone.js:10423
        at loadExif (dropzone.js:10346)
        at HTMLImageElement.img.onload (dropzone.js:10357)
    emit @ dropzone.js:8185
    (anonymous) @ dropzone.js:10197
    (anonymous) @ dropzone.js:10423
    loadExif @ dropzone.js:10346
    img.onload @ dropzone.js:10357
    load (async)
    createThumbnailFromUrl @ dropzone.js:10344
    fileReader.onload @ dropzone.js:10294
    load (async)
    createThumbnail @ dropzone.js:10283
    _processThumbnailQueue @ dropzone.js:10196
    (anonymous) @ dropzone.js:10179
    setTimeout (async)
    _enqueueThumbnail @ dropzone.js:10178
    addFile @ dropzone.js:10113
    (anonymous) @ dropzone.js:9533
    activestorage.js:739 POST 

http://localhost:5000/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
    create @ activestorage.js:739
    (anonymous) @ activestorage.js:873
    fileReaderDidLoad @ activestorage.js:620
    (anonymous) @ activestorage.js:605
    load (async)
    create @ activestorage.js:604
    create @ activestorage.js:584
    create @ activestorage.js:865
    start @ dropzone_controller.js:93
    (anonymous) @ dropzone_controller.js:31
    setTimeout (async)
    (anonymous) @ dropzone_controller.js:30
    emit @ dropzone.js:8185
    addFile @ dropzone.js:10111
    (anonymous) @ dropzone.js:9533
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my `dropzone_controller.js` file with stimulus

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus";
import Dropzone from "dropzone";
import "dropzone/dist/min/dropzone.min.css";
import "dropzone/dist/min/basic.min.css";
import { DirectUpload } from "@rails/activestorage";

export default class extends Controller {
    static targets = ["input"];

    connect() {
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        this.inputTarget.disable = true;
        this.inputTarget.style.display = "none";
        const dropzone = new Dropzone(this.element, {
            url: "/",
            maxFiles: "10",
            maxFilesize: "10",
        });


        dropzone.on("addedfile", (file) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (file.accepted) {
                    const upload = new DirectUpload(file, this.url);
                    upload.create((error, attributes) => {
                        this.hiddenInput = document.createElement("input");
                        this.hiddenInput.type = "hidden";
                        this.hiddenInput.name = this.inputTarget.name;
                        this.hiddenInput.value = attributes.signed_id; << error here
                        this.inputTarget.parentNode.insertBefore(
                            this.hiddenInput,
                            this.inputTarget.nextSibling
                        );
                        dropzone.emit("success", file);
                        dropzone.emit("complete", file);
                    });
                }
            }, 500);
        });
    }

    get url() {
        return this.inputTarget.getAttribute("data-direct-upload-url");
    }
}
```

When I attempt to upload an image, an error related to blob shows up.
`Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "signed_id", blob is undefined`

Comment: When using rails' methods to submit forms with JS (like `remote: true`) it internally adds the CSRF token to the request's headershttps://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/utils/csrf.coffee. You'll have to hook into Dropzone's request callbacks to add the token with a similar code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149023/how-to-include-the-csrf-token-in-the-headers-in-dropzone-upload-request

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include the CSRF token in the headers in Dropzone upload request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149023/how-to-include-the-csrf-token-in-the-headers-in-dropzone-upload-request)

Comment: @arieljuod Sadly it doesn't it. Still have same error.

Comment: [Possibly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20875591/4575793) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35181340/4575793) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63911493/4575793). For me, it helped to give an authenticityToken from the controller to the frontend and just give that back to the backend unchanged when the request is done.